# Error importing middleware django.middleware.cache: "No module named memcache"

Tags: python, django, memcached

shared host: mochahost, setup memcached. Error importing middleware django.middleware.cache: "No module named memcache"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/opt/Python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1537, 
in HandlerDispatch
default=default_handler, arg=req, silent=hlist.silent)

File "/opt/Python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1229, 
in _process_target
result = _execute_target(config, req, object, arg)

File "/opt/Python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1128, 
in _execute_target
result = object(arg)

File "/home2/minhhien/webapps/django/core/handlers/modpython.py", line 180, in handler
return ModPythonHandler()(req)

File "/home2/minhhien/webapps/django/core/handlers/modpython.py", line 142, in __call__
self.load_middleware()

File "/home2/minhhien/webapps/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in 
load_middleware
raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % 
(mw_module, e))

ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware django.middleware.cache: "No module 
named memcache"
```

Please help me ! ( sorry, not good english :D )

Comment: Have you installed memcached? `pip install python-memcached`

Comment: Maybe this heroku guide on how to setup memcache with django can help you.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-memcache#start-using-memcache

Answer (score 6):

`memcached` is a daemon. For your program to use it you must load a driver module that allows you to access it.

> After installing Memcached itself, you’ll need to install a memcached
>   binding. There are several python memcached bindings available; the
>   two most common are python-memcached and pylibmc.

[Quote reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#memcached)

Comment: I've downloaded python-memcached-1:53, but did not know how to install on mochahost.

Comment: It depends what kind of access you get on mochahost. Maybe you could talk to their support team?

Comment: Thanks to @BoJack_Horseman for the clarifying edit and link addition.